# View Long filenames with question mark in Browser

Tags: apache, firefox, escaping

I have a file called **34.php?session=2534464a39a2c97cb7113689726a4e52** in my /var/www/html folder but I can't view this file in the browser. I want my browser to execute this code via PHP from the browser but It doesn't :(
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to URL encode the `?`, otherwise it won't be interpreted as a part of the filename. Try `34.php%3Fsession=2534464a39a2c97cb7113689726a4e52`